# How can we use Open SSL with Delphi iOS?

Tags: ios, security, delphi, ssl, firemonkey

Apple has introduced a few changes with it's App Transport Security when working with Open SSL and I can't make it work on `iOS`.

> “App Transport Security is a feature that improves the security of
>   connections between an app and web services. The feature consists of
>   default connection requirements that conform to best practices for
>   secure connections. Apps can override this default behavior and turn
>   off transport security. Transport security is available in iOS 9.0 or
>   later, and in OS X v10.11 and later.”

When trying to connect to our server, I get the following response error:

> "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made."

Then, I found [this tutorial](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/using_ssl_delphi_ios.html) and discovered that all we need to do is to include the unit `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders_Static` in one of the uses statements of the project.

I did add the unit and both `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a.` libraries to the project but so far I'm getting the same response error.

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable **ATS**, you need to additionally follow this steps from [this official embarcadero documentation](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/how-to-use-custom-info-plist-xml-to-support-ios-9-s-new-app-transport-security-feature):

Open your **Info.plist** and add the following lines:

```
<key> NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
</dict>
```

This will disable Apple’s App Transport Security feature for **all** HTTP communications used by the application, for example if you use the `TWebBrowser` or Project Indy's `HTTP` component.

Your project’s `Info.plist` file is **regenerated** every time deployment is done. You need to save the file to a different location, like your project directory for example. (*Note that the 32-bit and 64-bit versions are slightly different*).

Make your changes in the newly saved file and go to the **Deployment Manager** (Project -> Deployment). Make sure the configuration is set correctly and **uncheck the default Info.plist**.

Add the new custom version and **make sure you set the Remote Name to “Info.plist” (case-sensitive)**. Do this for both the 64-bit and 32-bit deployment.

Comment: May be more useful - free utilite iOS9Fix from http://tmssoftware.com/site/blog.asp?post=317 Do it once and forget about .plist file.